# mysql searching, condition from another table

Tags: mysql, search

I have two tables. products and productgroups.
I use

```
"SELECT * FROM `product` `t` 
  WHERE (name LIKE '%test%' OR ean LIKE '%test%') 
    AND closed=0 "
```

To search in products. Now I have another table called `productgroups`. Every product has its own `productgroup_id`. I need to show only those products that have their `productgroup_id.closed=0`.
If `productgroup.closed = 1` it shouldn't display it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
INNER JOIN productgroup pg ON (pg.id = p.productgroup_id)
WHERE (p.name LIKE '%test%' OR p.ean LIKE '%test%') 
AND p.closed=0
AND pg.closed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've missed the complexity in the problem, but...

```
SELECT * FROM
products INNER JOIN
     productgroups ON product.productGroup_id = productgroups.Id
WHERE
(products.name LIKE '%test%' OR products.ean LIKE '%test%') AND products.closed=0 and productgroups.closed = 0
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

just use an [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  product t 
INNER JOIN 
  productgroups g ON t.productgroup_id = g.id
WHERE
  (t.name LIKE '%test%' OR t.ean LIKE '%test%') 
AND
  g.closed = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product t 
INNER JOIN productgroup pg ON t.productgroup_id = pg.id
WHERE (t.name LIKE '%test%' OR t.ean LIKE '%test%') AND t.closed=0 AND pg.Closed = 0
```